# I have a programming task where I can't get any further

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I have to do:

Create a simple HTML form with 2 input fields and a button. In addition, create a rectangle with 100x100px and additionally define 3 styles with a background color larger (red), equal (green) and smaller (yellow). Program a "check" function that is executed when the button is clicked and depending on the two numbers sets the color on the rectangle.

my code:

```js
function reckteck() {
  var gr = document.getElementById('demo1').value;
  var gl = document.getElementById('demo1').value;
  var kl = document.getElementById('demo1').value;
  if (demo1 > demo2) {
    document.getElementById("eck").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else if (demo1 == demo2) {
    document.getElementById("eck").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else if (demo1 < demo2) {
    document.getElementById("eck").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="demo1" type="text" name="yo1" value="demo1">
<input id="demo2" type="text" name="yo2" value="demo2">
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="reckteck()">pruefen</button>
<br><br>
<svg id="eck">
  <rect width="100px" height="100px"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Now we know what you have to do, but we don't know what your problem is. What part of the requirement does not work in your code?

Comment: Your `demo1` and `demo2` is nowhere defined, also `gr`, `gl` and `kl` is same DOM element and never used. Fix that. Also your `#demo1` and `#demo2` has string values, so you can't simply compare using `>`

Comment: "*Write a title that summarizes the specific problem*". Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My code just works for the color green. The others doesn t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

```js
function reckteck() {
  var yo1 = document.getElementById('yo1').value;
  var yo2 = document.getElementById('yo2').value;
  if (yo1 > yo2) {
    document.getElementById("eck").style.fill = "red";
  } else if (yo1 == yo2) {
    document.getElementById("eck").style.fill = "green";
  } else if (yo1 < yo2) {
    document.getElementById("eck").style.fill = "yellow";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="yo1" type="number" value="1">
<input id="yo2" type="number" value="2">
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="reckteck()">pruefen</button>
<br><br>
<svg id="eck">
   <rect width="100px" height="100px"></rect>
</svg>
```